# Set c.cfg.Global.ElbSecurityGroup in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create an ElasticLoadBalancer for a Kubernetes cluster running on EKS. I would like to avoid creating a new security group and instead use one that I specify. From the Kubernetes [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9fd23b217800a312a45dbaedb70f4ffa65ec661b/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/aws/aws.go#L3309) (below) it appears that I can accomplish this by setting `c.cfg.Global.ElbSecurityGroup`.

```golang
func (c *Cloud) buildELBSecurityGroupList(...) {
    var securityGroupID string

    if c.cfg.Global.ElbSecurityGroup != "" {
            securityGroupID = c.cfg.Global.ElbSecurityGroup
    } else {
            ...
    }
...
}
```

How can I set the Kubernetes global config value `ElbSecurityGroup`?

Related and outdated question: [Kubernetes and AWS: Set LoadBalancer to use predefined Security Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748320/kubernetes-and-aws-set-loadbalancer-to-use-predefined-security-group)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [kops documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cluster_spec.md#elbsecuritygroup) you can do it by editing kops cluster configuration:

### cloudConfig

#### elbSecurityGroup

WARNING: this works only for Kubernetes version above 1.7.0.

To avoid creating a security group per elb, you can specify security group id, that will be assigned to your LoadBalancer. It must be security group id, not name. `api.loadBalancer.additionalSecurityGroups` must be empty, because Kubernetes will add rules per ports that are specified in service file. This can be useful to avoid AWS limits: 500 security groups per region and 50 rules per security group.

```
spec:
  cloudConfig:
    elbSecurityGroup: sg-123445678
```